# Geometrical meaning of the commutator of vectors on a manifold

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors

On a manifold, vectors do not describe finite displacements, unlike in euclidean geometry, but they do describe infinitesimal displacements, so we can take two vectors, $v^a$ and $w^a$ to span an infinitesimal parallelogram.

I would like to understand how
$ v^a w^b−w^a v^b$ is what describes the "infinitesimal parallelogram" spanned by $v$ and $w$.

For example, a vector is (parallel) transported from a point $P$ to a point $P'$, along two different paths: the first $ P \rightarrow P_{1} \rightarrow P'$ consists of two infinitesimal shifts,
the second $ P \rightarrow P_{2} \rightarrow P'$ consists of the same shifts but in reverse order.

How are the movements represented ?

Comment: 1. Where is this a *physics* question rather than one about [math.SE]? 2. Who claims that this is an "infinitesimal parallelogram"? Where did you get that expression from? There is no "commutator of vectors" on a manifold, there is only a *commutator of vector fields*, cf. [Lie bracket of vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields).

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand what (as you put it), $v^aw^b-w^av^b$ means, let me clarify some details. The commutator in differential geometry can be thought of as a measure of curvature; it doesn't tell you *how* the space is curved, but more or less how the two vectors you put into the commutator *would* be on the curved surface with respect to one another. I also want to make it completely clear that these are not just vectors, but vector *fields*. So, lets take two examples:

If $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are directional derivatives, then their commutator would be, $[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}] = \partial_\mathbf{u}\partial_\mathbf{v}-\partial_\mathbf{v}\partial_\mathbf{u}$. But for physics (since we are on a physics forum), this is not exactly helpful...

If we wanted the commutator of two vector fields in *any* coordinate basis, then consider the following,
$\begin{align*}
[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}]f & = u^\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\left(v^\beta \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\beta}\right) - v^\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\left(u^\beta \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\beta}\right)\\
& = \left[ \left(u^\alpha v^\beta_{,\alpha} - v^\alpha u^\beta_{,\alpha}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta} \right]f\\
& = \left(u^\alpha v^\beta_{,\alpha} - v^\alpha u^\beta_{,\alpha}\right)\mathbf{e}_\beta,\\
\end{align*}$

where we first started out in a specific coordinate basis, but then moved to a general one by replacing the partial derivative. So, we can see that the commutator between two different vector fields really depends on out choice of coordinate frame, and is a measure of the difference between how tangent vectors behave along a curved surface.

Finally, relating back to your remark on "how is it related to an infinitesimal parallelogram," draw out a vector **u** that is perpendicular to the starting point of another vector **v**. Now, take the opposite vector of each, and start from where they ended (so, wherever **u** ended, place **v** and vice versa). If you did it correctly, then there should be a gap between the two ending vectors. This gap is *literally* $[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}]$. That is why it can be though of as an "infinitesimal parallelogram."